# Loading swf into another swf - child swf stage problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So Im loading movie B into movie A - using Loader class. 
All works well. But on one of the clients machine the child swf is not added to the display list. Instead he gets five running dots on screen. He sees preloader, but when its done loading the application crashes with those dots running.
I guess somehow it tried to add the child swf to stage before stage was available, although I added correct script to check for the stage in child swf

In child swf constructor:

```
if (stage) {
    init();
}else {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    //...... the rest
}
```

I suspect that clients machine is slow and that could be possible cause to this.
[image]

Everywhere else it works as expected - both mac and pc.

Any thoughts, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't usually need code in the child swf to add it to the stage, the parent should be responsible of adding the child to the stage once its loaded. What does the child swf do? Is it just an animation or does it run its own code?

Comment: Its actually quite the opposite - you need to make sure that stage exists before adding the child swf, which has references to the stage.

Comment: The parent will know about the stage long before the child arrives

Answer (score 0):

First thing as you said it works well on several machines including your (mac), I would think it could either be a browser problem as your client may have a different browser, or flash Version.

From the information you provided me i suggest you follow up on the platform your clients running it on, for instance Windows XP, Vista or 7.
Cross check with your browser, Explorer, Fire Fox or Chrome, just to name the most common.
Also how the Flash file is embedded into HTML or not, This may have effect on different browsers

Check your Clients Flash version, they may simply just need to update it.could be corrupt
Also in your question you should just type the link your SWF is located then we all can just check it and see how common this error is.

Last thing to note it may be your code but you havent posted your loader class for either the community or i to see. its all speculation let us no how you go.

Comment: The flash thingy is for bank, so because of security and other mumbo jumbo reasons - they can't update the flash player to the newer version.
Flash is embedded using latest swfobject.
Its hard to pinpoint the problem because it only happens on this one particular laptop in the bank.... if only they could update the flash player then I guess that would solve the problem.
Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the movie clip loaded is compiled for a newer version of flash than the client has. Check the flash version of the player and the SWFs to be sure that's not the case.